# Can I move the number centered at the bottom 2 to the left hand side?

Tags: xetex, numbering, pdf

Can I move the number centered at the bottom 2 [in the very last line of this Question] to the **left** hand side ?

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}% MWE only

\pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{(\paperheight-2cm)/(\paperwidth-3cm)}% 1cm margin
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\delta}{\paperwidth-2cm-2*\scale*(\paperheight-3cm)-4mm}% 4mm fudge factor

\newcommand\gettitle[1]{%
  \directlua{%
    local filename = kpse.find_file("#1", 'graphic/figure')
    doc = pdfe.open(filename)
    info = pdfe.getinfo(doc)
    title = info['Title']
    tex.print(title)
  }}

\begin{document}

%  \includepdf[scale=1.02, nup=2x1,pages=1-8,trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cm,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{sh1.pdf}

%pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 7.0cm,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{example-image-duck.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: IMHO it is always better, if the shown image really shows the result of the shown code …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page number in the middle of the landscape page is the page number of your article class document. It is there because of `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}`. (Just a note: `pagecommand={}` would be shorter and would have the same result in the example.)

Because IMHO this page number does not make any sense, I would just remove the page number by removing the pagecommand option.

But if you really want to move it, use e.g., [`fancyhdr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or [`scrlayer-scrpage`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage) to configure another placement of the page number. Here an (shorten) example using `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[footwidth=paper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{plain}
\cfoot*{}
\ifoot*{\makebox[.5\paperwidth][c]{\pagemark}}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[nup=2x1,height=\paperheight-7.5cm,delta=5cm 0pt,pages=1-,pagecommand={}]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image: two pages of output using scrlayer-scrpage]

See the manual for more information about `\cfoot`, `\ifoot` and `\pagemark`. The manual also explains how to define new page styles instead of using the already defined page style `plain`.

Alternatively once again remove option `pagecommand` and use option `picturecommand` to `\put` `\thepage` wherever you want it (shorten example):

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[nup=2x1,height=\paperheight-7.5cm,delta=5cm 0pt,pages=1-,picturecommand={\put(.25\paperwidth,3.3cm){\thepage}}]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image: two pages of output using picturecommand]

Comment: It works. Could you please add the following feature ? I would like to have three (and the same) page numbers at the bottom of each page. One Roman , one Hebrew and one Arabic. Is that possible ? I prefer modifying your first solution.

Comment: @user2925716 IMHO this is a new question and should should ask a new one. However, for Roman numbers you can simply add something like `\Roman{page}` or `\roman{page}` to the definition of `\pagemark`, e.g., use `\thepage -- \Roman{page}` instead of `\thepage` only. For Hebrew AFAIK you first would have to load the language and switch to the language. And I cannot tell you much about using Hebrew numbers, because I don't known Hebrew and never typeset a Hebrew document.